# Javascript TypeError Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, command-line

I am getting the following error and am not sure how to resolve it. I have tried looking at similar errors on SO but am not sure they are applicable. I have an array called 'current'. The issue may be related to scope, but I have tried modifying the scopes of a few variables to global, etc. to make it work and it is not yet.

```
  currentLen = current.length - 1;
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/blabla.js:41:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

Comment: It means that the value of the variable "current" is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

The error itself very clear. The current array is undefined; To avoid getting these error you can check for the existence of the array.

> currentLen = current && current.length - 1;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Array.isArray(current)) {
  // current exists and it is an array, therefore the length
  // attribute is guaranteed to exist
}
else {
  // Write some code to handle the case when current is not an array
}
```